# .jar File Not Working With Windows Scheduler

Tags: java, batch-file, windows-task-scheduler

Hi all so i have wrote a program in java (using eclipse) and exported single class program to a .jar file. This program also starts a batch file. When i double-click the .jar file the jar runs perfectly and starts the batch file.

But what i want to do is for the .jar file to run every weekly, so with windows scheduler i created a task with the action being the .jar file. This did not work. I then read somewhere that windows scheduler dose not like .jar so i thought of making a second batch file(start.bat) to start the .jar which would then start the first batch file.

The command in my start.bat is

**java -jar myJar.jar**

When i double click the start.bat file everything works. But when i set the windows scheduler to start this task i get the following error message for a cmd window

**Error: Unable to access jarfile myJar.jar**

This really has me stumped as all the files are in the same directory.
Any help would be seriously be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: use the full path of myJar.jar instead of a relative path - the running directory of the windows scheduler is C:\Windows\System32 and your jar-file is probably not in this directory.

Comment: Try by giving complete path of `myJar.jar` within your batch file.

Comment: Thanks a million, that was it.. Stupid mistake, thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously this comment was the answer:

use the full path of myJar.jar instead of a relative path - the running directory of the windows scheduler is C:\Windows\System32 and your jar-file is probably not in this directory.

Answer (score 0):

Task Scheduler cannot run .jar directly you need to run it via command prompt.
Because the task scheduler runs the .bat via cmd its default executing location i.e, C:/windows/system32 we need to change the path.
While scheduling task in scheduler call TaskName.bat as action.
SO,

Create a batch file "TaskName.bat" In TaskName.bat
Enter the Following

> **@echo off**
>
> **cd "Path to the jar file Example C:\MyFolder"**
>
> **java -jar Nameofthejar.jar**
>
> **pause**

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the following steps you will not get any issues.

#### Step 0 : Setup

[image]

Add `app.schedule.externally_managed=true` in `application.properties`

#### Step 1: Create a New Task

Click Create

[image]

Provide details

Configure for **Windows 10** is important
[image]

#### Step 2: Trigger Details

[image]

#### Step 3: Action Details

[image]

#### Step 4: Actions

Make sure all the checkboxes are unchecked as shown below, **this is important**
[image]

#### Step 5: View Task Details

[image]

Refer [this](https://github.com/mnadeem/wishing-app/wiki/Invoking-Using-Windows-Task-Scheduler-At-Startup) and [this](https://github.com/mnadeem/wishing-app/wiki/Invoking-Using-Windows-Task-Scheduler-on-a-schedule-basis) for more details